# Replacing only the fully matched words in a string

Tags: python, regex, list, replace

I have a list of names and I would like that when their full occurrence exists in the String they are replaced by the word `'PERSON'`. However with my below code, a partial match is also replaced by `'PERSON'`.

This is what I have:

```
test = 'Testes huius rey sunt hij, videlicet, Magnificus Dominus Periohannes de Mazara, nobilis Georgius de la Chabica, Nicolaus Manfridus de Caxario et alij.'

testres = re.compile("|".join(names)).sub('PERSON', test)
```

Result:

```
'Testes huius rey sunt hij, videlicet, Magnificus Dominus PERSONohannes de Mazara, nobilis PERSONorgius de la Chabica, PERSON PERSON de Caxario et alij.'
```

Since `'Peri'` is in the list, `'Periohannes'` is replaced as `'PERSONohannes'`

How can I fix that?

Comment: Instead of 'names' , use sorted(names,reverse=True).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of joining the list of names, find all words in the string, and check if each word found belongs in `names`:

```
import re
test = 'Testes huius rey sunt hij, videlicet, Magnificus Dominus Periohannes de Mazara, nobilis Georgius de la Chabica, Nicolaus Manfridus de Caxario et alij.'
new_test = re.sub('\w+', lambda x:'PERSON' if x.group() in names else x.group(), test)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the word-boundary anchor, `\b` is for:

```
>>> test = 'Testes huius rey sunt hij, videlicet, Magnificus Dominus Periohannes de Mazara, nobilis Georgius de la Chabica, Nicolaus Manfridus de Caxario et alij.'
>>> names = 'Nicolaus', 'Manfridus', 'Peri'
>>> names_regex = re.compile(r'\b'+'|'.join(names)+r'\b')
>>> names_regex.sub('PERSON',test)
'Testes huius rey sunt hij, videlicet, Magnificus Dominus Periohannes de Mazara, nobilis Georgius de la Chabica, PERSON PERSON de Caxario et alij.'
>>> test = 'Testes huius rey sunt hij, videlicet, Magnificus Dominus Periohannes de Mazara, nobilis Georgius de la Chabica, Nicolaus, Manfridus, de Caxario et alij.'
>>> names_regex.sub('PERSON',test)
'Testes huius rey sunt hij, videlicet, Magnificus Dominus Periohannes de Mazara, nobilis Georgius de la Chabica, PERSON, PERSON, de Caxario et alij.'
```

Note, it works more generally than just spaces on either end... i.e. with the comma in the second example.